# Why doesn't my webapi endpoint not return the expected output in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-web-api

I have an API with one Get action which looks like the following:

```
public string GetSearchEshtrak(string A_SHENASEHG)
    {

        var sample1 = new ObjectParameter("oUTSHENASEHP", typeof(string));
        var sample2 = new ObjectParameter("oUTAMT", typeof(int));

         return (db.USSD_100(A_SHENASEHG, sample1, sample2).ToString());

    }
```

Everything appears to run correctly and I see my  `USSD_100()` method is also returning the expected results.

However, when calling the endpoint with my browser Firefox the result is as follows:

`<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">-1</string>`

This XML is not what I expected it to be and doesn't has any information from the sample1 and sample2 object.(sample1 and sample2 are my 2 numeric item I want showing in browser)

What do I have to do to return the output of procedure  `USSD_100()` correctly, so I can see the sample1 and sample2 as XML in the browser?

thanks.

Comment: Are you calling the API directly or from js like

Comment: Please post what you expect the xml to look like and also what is being returned from `db.USSD_100`.  You care calling `ToString()` which would suggest why you're seeing a string but it would really help seeing more information.